# Firestore snapshots simply stop working in Go

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Go app running on a GCloud Compute Engine Instance with Ubuntu 20.04 and whatever the latest ver of Go is for 20.04.

The app is highly reliant on a Firestore Snapshot listener. After a random period of time (hours to a week), the listener just stops working. No errors, nothing. It works flawless until then. I can even update Firestore myself and it still doesn't see the change. Restarting the app fixes it.

I've reported this possible bug to FireBase but haven't heard back yet. Does anyone see anything wrong with this code that might cause that?

I don't think there are any coding mistakes here. If so, it's because I anonymized the code a bit.

```
func UsersSnapShots() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    iter := usersdb.Where("connected", "==", 1).Where("status", "==", 1).OrderBy("name", firestore.Asc).Snapshots(ctx)
    defer iter.Stop()
    for {
        next, err := iter.Next()
        log.Printf("User change detected")
        users = make(map[string]interface{})
        if err == iterator.Done {
            log.Printf("users done. That shouldn't happen! Run this function again.")
            go UsersSnapShots()
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            sendOnlineUsers()
            log.Printf("USERS SNAPS ERROR: %v", err)
            go UsersSnapShots()
            return
        }
        doc := next.Documents
        for {
            docIter, err := doc.Next()
            if err == iterator.Done {
                break
            }
            t := docIter.Data()
            temp := []string{}
            //clients is a map of my websocket clients.
            safeClients := clients //maps are not thread safe. So let's make a copy.
            //Add the websocket IDs for these certain users to the map.
            for k, v := range safeClients {
                if v.email == t["email"] {
                    temp = append(temp, k)
                }
            }
            t["sockets"] = temp
            users[t["email"].(string)] = t
        }

        sendOnlineUsers() //Send all the logged in users to all the users' browsers.
        //log.Printf("users: %v", users)
    }
}
```

Comment: `safeClients` and `clients` refer to the same underlying map data. There's a data race if `clients` is modified concurrently by other goroutines. Run the application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) and fix the reported issues.

Comment: @MuffinTop but it doesn't crash and the clients var is fine. It's the users var that is not updating. Also, I think it's more of a problem of the snapshot not triggering? I'll still run the race detector, but even if it finds anything, I don't think that's this issue.

Comment: It looks like there's  also a  data race on `users`. Data races can cause programs to randomly break, just as your application does.

Comment: Rewriting that whole part now. Will update when I determine it fixed this bug. Thanks!

Comment: Even with mutex, I'm still seeing race conditions. I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: @grantespo. Nope I Dropped Google because of this. I forget the exact response I received after doing everything they asked. But it summarized to "Seems like it's happening but we aren't fixing it". This was years ago but I think I remember the root cause being: randomly firebase would save(or return?) in a different type. I use Go. So that would just halt the program. Their answer didn't fill me with confidence and made me think firebase was not for enterprise apps.

Comment: @Chemdream

It's an interesting issue. It seems like this snapshot listener bug occurs sporadically across multiple firestore SDK's with no known steps to reproduce. It's also strange that this issue still exists after so many years. Maybe it's some sort of memory leak in their core code which is probably filled with legacy tech debt, hence why no one has fixed it yet

Comment: @grantespo are you currently still having the same issue? If so, have you contacted Google support? They REALLY need to fix this.

Comment: All, I have never figured this out. Google stopped helping, I dropped Google for that project. I couldn't trust it to work.